# to attach a pdf/other file at time of envelope creation / draft envelope in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, attachment, envelope

The objective is to attach a pdf/other file at time of envelope creation / draft envelope. I am using PHP5 Docusign.

Please find attached herewith "create_proposal.php" as "create_proposal.txt" for reference.

```
// instantiate a new envelope attachment
$content_bytes = file_get_contents("test.pdf");
$doc1_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);

$document1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
'document_base64' => $doc1_b64,
'name' => 'Order acknowledgement', # can be different from actual file name
'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
'document_id' => '1' # a label used to reference the doc
]);

$envelop_definition->setDocuments([$document1]);
```

The response is :

```
<pre>DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException Object
(
[responseBody:protected] => O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:33:"TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT";s:7:"message";s:134:"The pagenumber specified in the tab element is not in the document that the tab refers to. Tab on Page 4 of Document 1 for Recipient 1";}
[responseHeaders:protected] => Array
(
[0] => HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[Cache-Control] => no-cache
[Content-Length] => 196
[Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
[X-RateLimit-Reset] => 1604228400
[X-RateLimit-Remaining] => 992
[X-RateLimit-Limit] => 1000
[X-BurstLimit-Remaining] => 499
[X-BurstLimit-Limit] => 500
[X-DocuSign-TraceToken] => 943befbf-c776-4d03-a091-be5202acede7
[X-DocuSign-Node] => DA4FE36
[Date] => Sun, 01 Nov 2020 10:10:54 GMT
[Vary] => Accept-Encoding
)
```

Please provide solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Manish, looking at the error it looks like it is something to do with assigning tags for the user. Can you provide more of your code as it is not clear if you are using template, how do you set the tabs etc. Have you tried to download and run the PHP code example from [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php). You can download a quickstart from [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) as well